# fscheck doesn't generate random enough data

Tags: f#, quickcheck, fscheck

I'm playing with FsCheck so I have this implementation:

```
let add a b = 
    if a > 100
    then failwith "nasty bug"
    else a + b
```

...and this FsCheck based test:

```
fun (a:int) -> (add a 0) = a
|> Check.QuickThrowOnFailure
```

and the test never fails. My guess is that the 100 values produced by the random generator are never bigger than 100.

Shouldn't the values be more "random"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When you use `Check.QuickThrowOnFailure`, it uses the configuration `Config.QuickThrowOnFailure`, which has these values:

```
> Config.QuickThrowOnFailure;;
val it : Config =
  {MaxTest = 100;
   MaxFail = 1000;
   Replay = null;
   Name = "";
   StartSize = 1;
   EndSize = 100;
   QuietOnSuccess = false;
   Every = <fun:get_Quick@342>;
   EveryShrink = <fun:get_Quick@343-1>;
   Arbitrary = [];
   Runner = <StartupCode$FsCheck>.$Runner+get_throwingRunner@355;}
```

The important values to consider here are `StartSize`, but particularly `EndSize`. Some of the generators in FsCheck uses the *size* context to determine the size or range of values it generates.

If you change the `EndSize` to e.g. `1,000` you can make your test fail:

```
> Check.One({Config.QuickThrowOnFailure with EndSize = 1000}, fun (a:int) -> (add a 0) = a);;
System.Exception: Falsifiable, after 15 tests (0 shrinks) (StdGen (1912816373,296229213)):
Original:
101
with exception:
> System.Exception: nasty bug
   at FSI_0040.add(Int32 a, Int32 b)
   at FSI_0055.it@69-6.Invoke(Int32 a)
   at FsCheck.Testable.evaluate[a,b](FSharpFunc`2 body, a a) in C:\Users\Kurt\Projects\FsCheck\FsCheck\src\FsCheck\Testable.fs:line 161

   at <StartupCode$FsCheck>.$Runner.get_throwingRunner@365-1.Invoke(String message) in C:\Users\Kurt\Projects\FsCheck\FsCheck\src\FsCheck\Runner.fs:line 365
   at <StartupCode$FsCheck>.$Runner.get_throwingRunner@355.FsCheck-IRunner-OnFinished(String , TestResult ) in C:\Users\Kurt\Projects\FsCheck\FsCheck\src\FsCheck\Runner.fs:line 365
   at FsCheck.Runner.check[a](Config config, a p) in C:\Users\Kurt\Projects\FsCheck\FsCheck\src\FsCheck\Runner.fs:line 275
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0055>.$FSI_0055.main@()
Stopped due to error
```