# How to create a generator with a fixed list of items for FsCheck

Tags: random, f#, fscheck

I originally tried to create a generator that have the first 5 elements fixed (and on any test using `Prop.forAll` the first five would always run), but failed in doing so.

Now I am trying to simplify this by having one generator for random data within a range, and one generator for non-random data, i.e., a fixed sequence. It is similar to `Gen.constant`, except that instead of one value, it is a sequence of values.

I have this (simplified reproducible example, works with NUnit and xUnit):

```
[<Property(Verbose = true, MaxTest=5)>]
static member MultiplyIdentityCornerCases () =
    Gen.elements [0L; -1L; 1L; Int64.MinValue; Int64.MaxValue]
    |> Arb.fromGen 
    |> Prop.forAll <| fun x -> x = x * 1L
```

The output is (no idea where the `null` comes from):

```
0:
<null>
9223372036854775807L
1:
<null>
-9223372036854775807L
2:
<null>
-9223372036854775807L
3:
<null>
1L
4:
<null>
-9223372036854775807L
Ok, passed 5 tests.
```

I'd like the output to contain all the five tests in the sequence, preferably, but not necessarily, in order. I know I can do this with NUnit (or any unit testing system) using a testdata provider, but I wonder whether I can do it with FsCheck (or whether I should, perhaps this is a bad idea).

I think using FsCheck is useful, as for the situation where there's more than one function argument, I want it to exhaustively test all combinations of the corner cases arguments I give it. This is hopefully easier with FsCheck than with a testdata provider.

Comment: Thinking out loud, one way of fixing this is perhaps using the non-randomness of the number generator (or check how that is done), for integers it seems to work exactly the way I need it to work (see FsCheck output of my [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40923916/how-to-use-fscheck-to-generate-random-numbers-as-input-for-property-based-testin?rq=1))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not aware that that's possible, but you can do this:

```
open System
open FsCheck
open FsCheck.Xunit

[<Property>]
let MultiplyIdentityCornerCases () =
    Gen.oneof [
        Gen.elements [Int64.MinValue; -1L; 0L; 1L; Int64.MaxValue]
        Arb.generate ]
    |> Arb.fromGen
    |> Prop.forAll <| fun x -> x = x * 1L
```

Two generators are passed to `Gen.oneof`, so each of these will generate approximately half of the values.

`Gen.elements` ought to pick uniformly from all values in the provided sequence, so it'll use e.g. `0L` 20% of the time, but only for those half when `Gen.oneof` uses `Gen.elements`.

In other words, each of those 'special' values will be generated 50% * 20% = 10% of the time.

By default, a property runs 100 test cases, so on average, it should generate 10 `0L` values, 10 `Int64.MinValue` values, and so on. That should often be good enough.

---

If it isn't, you can always do something like this:

```
open System
open Xunit
open FsCheck
open FsCheck.Xunit
open Swensen.Unquote

[<Theory>]
[<InlineData(Int64.MinValue)>]
[<InlineData(-1L)>]
[<InlineData( 0L)>]
[<InlineData( 1L)>]
[<InlineData(Int64.MaxValue)>]
let MultiplyIdentityCornerCases x = x =! x * 1L

[<Property>]
let MultiplyIdentityCornerCasesProperty x =
    MultiplyIdentityCornerCases x
```

Here, you define a Parameterized Test using xUnit.net's `[<Theory>]` feature, and feed it the five corner cases you are concerned with. When you run the tests, the test runner will run those five test cases.

Furthermore, it'll run `MultiplyIdentityCornerCasesProperty` because it's annotated with `[<Property>]`, and that function simply calls the other function.

Comment: I like the second code-snippet best. It's actually pretty neat.

Comment: Thanks again, Mark. I like the second approach, provided I could replace the static data for a data provider, but that shouldn't be a problem. For now I've used a variant of your first approach above, which seems to work fine in practice (and making sure that enough tests are run to hit all the probabilities with a certain certainty).